# Pair-wise intersection set operation between column values in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, set-intersection

I have a data frame with one column. Each value in this column is a list. For example,

```
     A
0   [1, 3, 4]
1   [43, 1, 42]
2   [50, 3]
```

I want to perform the set intersection operation between each list to find common elements and produce a data frame as below.

```
    0           1           2 
0   [1, 2, 3]   [1]         [3]
1   [1]         [43, 1, 42] []
2   [3]         []          [50, 3]
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this rather than looping over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) set to convert all values in `A` to `set` then [`broadcast`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) set intersection:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 3, 4], [43, 1, 42], [50, 3]]})

# Convert to set
a = df['A'].apply(set).values
# Broadcast set intersection
new_df = pd.DataFrame(a[:, None] & a)
```

`new_df`:

```
           0            1        2
0  {1, 3, 4}          {1}      {3}
1        {1}  {1, 42, 43}       {}
2        {3}           {}  {50, 3}
```

---

Or [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) can be used to convert to `list` if needed (it can also be used to convert to `set` instead of `apply`):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 3, 4], [43, 1, 42], [50, 3]]})

# Convert to set (using vectorize instead of apply):
a = np.vectorize(set, otypes=['O'])(df['A'])
# Broadcast set intersection and convert back to list
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.vectorize(list, otypes=['O'])(a[:, None] & a)
)
```

`new_df`:

```
           0            1        2
0  [1, 3, 4]          [1]      [3]
1        [1]  [1, 42, 43]       []
2        [3]           []  [50, 3]
```